# How to do conditional formatting in Google Sheets based off of Date?

Tags: date, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am looking for a way to color rows based on date. My hope is that every other day will alternate colors.

For example, I would like all of the rows with the same date, January 1st, 2023, to be one color. Then all of the rows with the next day, January 2nd, 2023, to be another color. Then each day would alternate back and forth.

[image]

There is plenty of info on conditional formatting. Just couldn't find alternating colors that switch back and forth based on date. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

To be more clear I am hoping that the entire row will alternate colors based on the date. Here is a better example:

[image]

Comment: Is there any date missing in between?

Comment: Sometimes yes... but not very often.

Comment: Yes sir... this answers my question perfectly. I apologize for asking a duplicate question. Thank you for your help. Very grateful for that. =)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the desired *conditional formatting* to range `A2:A` with custom formula

```
=if(isblank(A2),,arrayformula(mod(countif(A$2:A2<>A$1:A1,"=true"),2)))=1
```

Regarding your edit, you can indeed apply the same format in column A to other columns by including those columns in the range of the *conditional formatting* rule. For example, replace `A2:A` with `A2:B`

---

It is easier to see why this works with some helper columns.

The above is equivalent to the followings.

In B2, put

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A),,A:A<>A2:A))
```

In C2, put

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(isblank(B2:B),,mod(countIFs(B$2:B,"=true",row(B$2:B),"<="&ROW(B$2:B)),2)))
```

Apply the desired *conditional formatting* to range A2:A and use custom formula `=C2=1`.

And you will have the desired effect.

---

The helper column B simply checks if a date is different from the preceding row. If it is, we will mark it as `TRUE`.

Helper column C is a running sum of the number of `TRUE` values in column B. A running sum of `TRUE` values mark the number of distinct dates. With this particular running sum formula, a second helper column is needed because the syntax checker in Google Sheet considers `A:A<A2:A` of different length. And that's also why helper columns are needed with this particular formula.

We also wrap the running sum formula with `mod(_,2)` to divide the distinct dates into 2 groups. Now in column C, you will have label 1 and 0 for the alternating groups of dates in column A. Hence the custom formula `=C2=1` for *conditional formatting*.

But to take a step back, custom formula in *conditional formatting* has implicit iterations built-in and produces a different formula for every cell in the range implicitly. That makes running sum a single formula on your end. That's how you can go from the helper columns to the simplified answer at the beginning.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately I did not have the desired effect. Perhaps I am doing something wrong.  Ty for your help @Argyll. I will keep messing with this.

Comment: @AbleArcher: It works in my sheet. Could you share a live sheet so that I or others can spot any particularity in your true intended example? I also just realized you can take advantage of the built-in iteration in conditional formatting and avoid helper columns with the exact same formulas. You are welcome to try that after you refresh and see my edit. However, if you had problems earlier, I'd expect the same problems to re-appear. Hence, live sheet.

Comment: Honestly would love to try anything you recommend. I assume the error is on my end as I have a lot to learn with Google Sheets. Not sure how to do a live sheet.

Comment: @AbleArcher: Excel? The answer is for Google Sheet. You put Google Sheet as tag in your question right? I honestly do not recommend dealing with conditional formatting in Excel. Unless recent updates had major changes, conditional formatting is imho a weakness of Excel. (It's not the only one.)

Comment: You are correct. I made a Typo by referring to Excel. Please forgive me. I will spend some time working on your answer.